# How to set page to byte mapping array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, rest

I am trying to upload a file using RestAPI.
As part of this , I have an API request which requires me to set "pageToByte" object in the request.

This object should divide the file content bytes to pages depending on the file size . Here's the code I am using , but this is not calculating the logic accurately. Can somebody help? Thanks.

```
public Object setPageToByteMapping(String fileName) {
        Map<Integer, String> pageToByte = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> lines = FileUtility.readLineByLine(fileName);
        if (lines != null) {
            if (lines.size() <= 100) {
                pageToByte.put(1, "0-" + String.valueOf(FileUtility.getFileSize(fileName) - 1));
            } else {
                int startBytes = 0;
                int endBytes = 0;
                for (int k = 1; k <= FileUtility.getPageCount(fileName); k++) {
                    for (int i = ((k * 100) - 100); i < Math.min(lines.size(), k * 100); i++) {
                        endBytes = endBytes + lines.get(i).getBytes().length;
                    }
                    pageToByte.put(Integer.valueOf(k), Integer.toString(startBytes) + '-' + Integer.toString(endBytes - 1));
                    startBytes = endBytes;
                }
            }
        }
        return pageToByte;
    }
```